# is there any difference between two methods that re-initializing vector?

Tags: c++, vector, std, initializing

I use two methods when I re-initialize vector

```cpp
vector<int> vec(1000, 1);

//first
vec.assign(1000, 2);

//second
vec = vector<int>(1000, 3);
```

I think these two methods are produce same result, but I found that the second method takes up less memory.

Is there something difference between these two method??

Comment: They won't produce same result because value to assign differs.

Comment: how do you know that the second takes up less memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is how the internal memory of the `std::vector` is handled.

With

```
std::vector<int> vec(1000, 1);
```

You created a new `std::vector` called `vec`. It allocates memory to hold 1000 `int`s and initializes their values to `1`.

In the first method:

```
vec.assign(1000, 2);
```

You then tell `vec` to reuse that allocated memory, where the 1000 `int`s live. They are simply overwritten by values of `2`.

In the second method:

```
std::vec = std::vector<int>(1000, 3);
```

You actually do two things - you create a new `std::vector` which allocates memory for 1000 `int`s and initializes their values to `3`. Then this new vector is *move assigned* to `vec`, which in turn will throw away its memory of `2`s and take the internal memory of the anonymous unnamed vector with its `3`s, because its a so-called *rvalue*.

The overall memory consumption should be the same in the end, although when using the 2nd method, for a moment you have 2 allocated memory regions of 1000 `int`s each, alive at the same time.

Comment: `std::vector::assign` invalidates iterators because it potentially needs to reallocate, or is there a different reason?

Comment: It could reallocate , or you could also `std::vector::assign` a different i.e. smaller count of integers, which would at least invalidate the past the end iterator.

Comment: @Superlokkus It always invalidates all of them according to cppreference. Perhaps to let implementors create a new `vector` and just `swap` with that. Otherwise, assigning a smaller count could have just `resize`d and assigned to the elements that would be left, which would leave iterators still valid (except the `end()` iterator - which may be a reason to say they are _all_ invalidated).

Comment: @idclev463035818 `std::vector::assign` doesn't "assign" elements (nice name, isn't it). It "replaces" elements. The new elements will be separate objects from the previous elements even though they might share the address.

Comment: @eerorika Ooo... "_replace_" ...  wording matters.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I did not say it would not invalidate the other iterators, I was simply ask what other reasons could be, why an implementation would invalidate them, and did not say the list is complete.

Comment: @Superlokkus Yeah, you said "_at least_" and I just wanted to clarify that it'll invalidate all of them no matter the count.

Comment: @eerorika I wrote an answer by guessing what `std::vector::asign` does by its name. It was a good leason to learn that names can be extremely misleading. I hope nobody saw that non-sense answer :P

Comment: @TedLyngmo Since we both are already showing of on our alleged C++ knowledge? Could you help me out and show me the exact position where the public available standard draft describe the `std::vector::assign` function? I would only find it in the header synopsis but nowhere the according descroption.

Comment: "_Since we both are already showing of on our alleged C++ knowledge_" - I wasn't aiming to show off - merely to clarify something that could _perhaps_ be misunderstood.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was hoping you would let me get away with this;-). But seriously oddly I cant not find the actual definition of `std::vector::assign` or `std::deque::assign` besides their mere declaration in the header synopsis.

Comment: @Superlokkus Neither can I :-) Cheers!

Comment: @Superlokkus Or perhaps here it is: http://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts#4

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you, because searching "void assign" would not find "assign void" as they wrote it, I was almost going to submit a defect report. Thanks for saving me from the shame :-)